# Making a class non-inheritable by defining default private constructor

Tags: c++

Although I have seen `final` and virtual inheritance methods achieve this, I cannot understand why defining no constructors, except a default private one, does not prevent a class from being inherited. (Also, base class's copy constructor and copy assignment methods should be declared private as a precaution.)

Basically what I mean is if a base class's constructor is private and it has no other constructors, then, when a derived class wants to extend this base class:

1. The derived class cannot call the default constructor of the base class because it is defined private
2. The derived class cannot call any non-default constructors of the base class since there are no such constructors

So it is a compile time error and I cannot find another way to get over this.

I am sure I am wrong somewhere; otherwise, I could find a page on the internet that offers this as a way of making a class non-inheritable, but please, explain to me why I am wrong.

Comment: You can use your approach too. If you dig deeper, you might find how the two approaches are different, and when you should use one vs the other.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you wondering *if* this works, or *why* it works, or how to get around it?

Comment: @R Sahu Can you, please, explain the difference or provide links-related keywords that I can read-search?

Comment: @meagar Actually, I haven't even tried the approach I mentioned but my wonderings would be if this works and if it works, why not mentioned as a way of making a class non-inheritable in literature?

Comment: @mualloc Because we have `final` now? Yes, of course you can use a private constructor for this, but why would you? That's the *wrong* solution now that `final` exists. You can use a wrench to hammer in a nail, but you shouldn't wonder why "the literature" doesn't bother to mention this fact when *hammers* exist.

Comment: @meager What is wrong with this solution? That is my question. Someone might have to work with an old compiler which 'final' does not exist. Actually, it happens very often for long-term projects.

Comment: @mualloc "Someone might have to work with an old compiler which 'final' does not exist" - then you should (kindly) lean on them until they agree to update their tool-chain to something more modern and then use `final` :-) That's the *proper* fix.

Comment: You can find places that talk about this technique and other ideas, from before "final" existed in C++. You just have to look at older posts/mailing list entries. For example: [this from 2009](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/12600/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` and private constructor are not the same thing.

Consider this:

```
struct A final {};
struct B: A {};

int main() {}
```

It won't compile, that's a fact.
Now consider this:

```
class A { A() {} };
struct B: A {};

int main() {}
```

It compiles. Ok, it happens that `B()` constructor is deleted but you are not using it. It won't compile if you change slightly the definition to:

```
struct B: A { B(): A() {} };
```

Anyway, the previous example just *works* (for some mean of *works*), so what's the difference?
`final` forbids inheritance. A private constructor doesn't allow you to construct objects of *that* type but you can still define *that* type. Therefore you can do something like this (that doesn't make much sense but gives you an idea):

```
#include<type_traits>

class A { A() {}};
struct B: A {};

template<typename T>
void f() {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, B>::value, "!");
    // ...
}

int main() {
    f<B>();
}
```

How is it that it compiles if you cannot inherit from `A`? Because your assumption was wrong, you can inherit from `A`. You can't construct an object of type `B`, but you can still use `B` as a type as long as you don't try to create instances. On the other side, if you put there `final` you get a compile-time error and that's all, you cannot use type `B` in any way.

Comment: class A 's constructor is public, so it is not what I am saying.

Comment: @mualloc default visibility of a class is `private`, thus `class C { C() {} };` is equivalent to `class C { private: C() {} };`. Constructor isn't public actually. If you try to construct a `B` in the second example it won't compile.

Comment: OK, you are right about the default visibility issue and thank you for your explanation. That is what I was looking for.

Comment: By the way, I am sorry for being such careless since I did not  compile the code that I described so that I could discover and define the problem better.

Comment: Actually, what are the differences between struct B: A {} and struct B: A { B(): A() {} }?

Comment: @mualloc In the first case, `B()` is implicitly deleted. In the second case it's ill-formed for `A()` isn't visible.

Comment: Doesn't compiler put B(): A() {} into B: A {} implicitly when programmer does not write specifically?

Comment: @mualloc In this case, no. The constructor is implicitly deleted for it would be ill-formed otherwise.

Comment: Maybe I am asking too much but let me tell you what I inferred and correct me if I am wrong: A default constructor is created by compiler if it is not defined by user and it is CALLED by user. In former, since B type is not created in main(), a default B constructor is not created and in latter, since a default constructor, which calls private default constructor of base class, is created by user, it does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Why would the standard forbid that? In theory, nothing prevents you from declaring your Derived class a friend of the Base class. That would ensure the only possible way to extend your base class is through very well known classes. I can't think of any practical case and I think it's bad, but it is POSSIBLE to do such horror...

```
struct BaseClass
{
friend struct DerivedClass;

private:
    BaseClass() {}
};

struct DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
public:
    DerivedClass() {}
};
```